# How to find out the size of a graphic object in Pine Script 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

*I need to find out the height of the graphical objects p1 and p2, just saying I need to turn p1 into a variable for plot(p1) to work, the problem is that p1 is not a variable. help with the solution of this situation*

```
indicator(title="Ichimoku Cloud", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true)
conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")
donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)


leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)


p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7,title="Leading Span A")

p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A,title="Leading Span B")
```

## I tried different ways, but the result is 1, it always gave an error

Comment: What do you mean by "height of the graphical object"?

Comment: I need to create a variable from p1 so that I can extract data from it, that is ( leadLine1 ) taking into account the offset ( offset = displacement - 1 ). I can't make a variable in which the offset will be taken into account